# How to use json_normalize from Pandas

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to use `json_normalize` from Pandas, but so far my efforts have yielded only errors. Can someone clue me in to what I'm doing wrong? I have a complex nested JSON and I would love to utilize pandas's powerful tools to analyze it.

Code (current attempt):

```
import json, pandas as pd

from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

df = pd.read_json('dir/data.json')

json_normalize(df,'aaa', 'bbb')
```

Errors have ranged from

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

to multiple `KeyError: 0` issues.

I have tried multiple keyword arguments to approach using this function, I tried to break the data into lines and recreate it line by line prior to normalization , and I read the [documentation for this function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) and googled the function in combination with the errors I'm getting. All have failed. I suspect it may be due to the fairly complex nature of `data.json`. I can use other methods, but they are very time intensive.

Apologies on formatting, It was my very first question. For the awesome person who responded with constructive feedback, here are a few lines taken from the middle of my data file:

```
{"_id" : { "$oid" : "52b213b38594d8a2be17c789" }, "approvalfy" : "2014", "board_approval_month" : "October", "boardapprovaldate" : "2013-10-29T00:00:00Z", "borrower" : "THE KINGDOM OF MOROCCO", "closingdate" : "2014-12-31T00:00:00Z", "country_namecode" : "Kingdom of Morocco!$!MA", "countrycode" : "MA", "countryname" : "Kingdom of Morocco", "countryshortname" : "Morocco", "docty" : "Program Document,Project Information Document,Project Information Document", "grantamt" : 0, "ibrdcommamt" : 200000000, "id" : "P130903", "idacommamt" : 0, "impagency" : "MINISTRY OF FINANCE", "lendinginstr" : "Development Policy Lending", "lendinginstrtype" : "AD", "lendprojectcost" : 200000000, "majorsector_percent" : [ { "Name" : "Public Administration, Law, and Justice", "Percent" : 34 }, { "Name" : "Public Administration, Law, and Justice", "Percent" : 33 }, { "Name" : "Public Administration, Law, and Justice", "Percent" : 33 } ], "mjsector_namecode" : [ { "name" : "Public Administration, Law, and Justice", "code" : "BX" }, { "name" : "Public Administration, Law, and Justice", "code" : "BX" }, { "name" : "Public Administration, Law, and Justice", "code" : "BX" } ], "mjtheme" : [ "Public sector governance", "Public sector governance", "Public sector governance" ], "mjtheme_namecode" : [ { "name" : "Public sector governance", "code" : "2" }, { "name" : "Public sector governance", "code" : "2" }, { "name" : "Public sector governance", "code" : "2" } ], "mjthemecode" : "2,2,2", "prodline" : "PE", "prodlinetext" : "IBRD/IDA", "productlinetype" : "L", "project_abstract" : { "cdata" : "The objective of this First Transparency and Accountability Development Policy Loan (DPL) Program for Morocco is to support the concretization of key new constitutional governance principles and rights, aimed at increasing transparency and accountability and enhancing citizen engagement and access to information. The series supports structural reforms strengthening economic governance across the public sector and new policies fostering more inclusive and open governance. The DPL has been prepared jointly with the European Union (EU) and the African Development Bank (AfDB), leveraging a further US$ 250 million in support of common key policy actions such as the budget, procurement and open governance reforms. The programmatic approach is warranted by the scope and depth of the government's governance reform program, the implementation of which will require time, assistance, and flexibility. This operation is complemented by the transition fund project supporting the implementation of Morocco's new governance framework. This US$ 4 million grant provides technical assistance for the implementation of structural reforms fostering public engagement; performance based budgeting and fiscal decentralization. The series adopts a holistic and integrated approach to enhance its impact. It is supporting governance reforms across the public sector covering the central government; State owned Enterprises, or SoEs and agencies, local governments as well as inter-governmental relations. The Bank has provided policy advice and technical assistance for the design of most policy measures and laws supported by this DPL, with the support from the MNA multi-donor trust fund. The transition fund governance project will support the implementation of these structural reforms. While building on the long-standing engagement with public administration reform, under the Public Administration Reform Loan (PARL) series, this program supports the concretization of the performance budgeting reform through the adoption and implementation of the new organic budget law and procurement decree. This DPL series also delves into new reform areas derived from the constitution such as access to information, public petitions, as well as into the governance of SoEs and local finances." }, "project_name" : "MA Accountability and Transparency DPL", "projectdocs" : [ { "DocTypeDesc" : "Program Document (PGD),  Vol.1 of 1", "DocType" : "PGD", "EntityID" : "000333037_20131009170139", "DocURL" : "http://www-wds.worldbank.org/servlet/WDSServlet?pcont=details&eid=000333037_20131009170139", "DocDate" : "30-SEP-2013" }, { "DocTypeDesc" : "Project Information Document (PID),  Vol.1 of 1", "DocType" : "PID", "EntityID" : "000231615_20121031105539", "DocURL" : "http://www-wds.worldbank.org/servlet/WDSServlet?pcont=details&eid=000231615_20121031105539", "DocDate" : "04-SEP-2012" }, { "DocTypeDesc" : "Project Information Document (PID),  Vol.1 of 1", "DocType" : "PID", "EntityID" : "000386194_20121016015521", "DocURL" : "http://www-wds.worldbank.org/servlet/WDSServlet?pcont=details&eid=000386194_20121016015521", "DocDate" : "04-SEP-2012" } ], "projectfinancialtype" : "IBRD", "projectstatusdisplay" : "Active", "regionname" : "Middle East and North Africa", "sector" : [ { "Name" : "General public administration sector" }, { "Name" : "Central government administration" }, { "Name" : "Public administration- Information and communications" } ], "sector1" : { "Name" : "General public administration sector", "Percent" : 34 }, "sector2" : { "Name" : "Central government administration", "Percent" : 33 }, "sector3" : { "Name" : "Public administration- Information and communications", "Percent" : 33 }, "sector_namecode" : [ { "name" : "General public administration sector", "code" : "BZ" }, { "name" : "Central government administration", "code" : "BC" }, { "name" : "Public administration- Information and communications", "code" : "BM" } ], "sectorcode" : "BM,BC,BZ", "source" : "IBRD", "status" : "Active", "supplementprojectflg" : "N", "theme1" : { "Name" : "Other accountability/anti-corruption", "Percent" : 33 }, "theme_namecode" : [ { "name" : "Other accountability/anti-corruption", "code" : "29" }, { "name" : "Other public sector governance", "code" : "30" }, { "name" : "Public expenditure, financial management and procurement", "code" : "27" } ], "themecode" : "27,30,29", "totalamt" : 200000000, "totalcommamt" : 200000000, "url" : "http://www.worldbank.org/projects/P130903?lang=en" }
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "52b213b38594d8a2be17c78a" }, "approvalfy" : "2014", "board_approval_month" : "October", "boardapprovaldate" : "2013-10-25T00:00:00Z", "borrower" : "GOVERNMENT OF SOUTH SUDAN", "country_namecode" : "Republic of South Sudan!$!SS", "countrycode" : "SS", "countryname" : "Republic of South Sudan", "countryshortname" : "South Sudan", "docty" : "Project Paper,Project Information Document", "envassesmentcategorycode" : "B", "grantamt" : 7530000, "ibrdcommamt" : 0, "id" : "P145339", "idacommamt" : 0, "impagency" : "MINISTRY OF AGRICULTURE, COOPERATIVES AND RURAL DEVELOPMENT", "lendinginstr" : "Specific Investment Loan", "lendinginstrtype" : "IN", "lendprojectcost" : 7530000, "majorsector_percent" : [ { "Name" : "Agriculture, fishing, and forestry", "Percent" : 50 }, { "Name" : "Health and other social services", "Percent" : 30 }, { "Name" : "Agriculture, fishing, and forestry", "Percent" : 20 } ], "mjsector_namecode" : [ { "name" : "Agriculture, fishing, and forestry", "code" : "AX" }, { "name" : "Health and other social services", "code" : "JX" }, { "name" : "Agriculture, fishing, and forestry", "code" : "AX" } ], "mjtheme" : [ "Rural development" ], "mjtheme_namecode" : [ { "name" : "Rural development", "code" : "10" }, { "name" : "", "code" : "2" } ], "mjthemecode" : "10,2", "prodline" : "RE", "prodlinetext" : "Recipient Executed Activities", "productlinetype" : "L", "project_abstract" : { "cdata" : "The development objective of the Additional Financing (AF) for the Emergency Food Crisis Response Project for South Sudan is to support adoption of improved technologies for food production by eligible beneficiaries, increase storage capacity for staples, and provide cash or food to eligible people participating in public works programs in selected counties in South Sudan. This is the third AF to the project and will be primarily used to scale-up and augment benefits to already participating beneficiaries and to expand project activities to four additional counties where recent monitoring points to significantly deteriorating food security. The AF will cover the costs associated with: (i) provision of agricultural inputs, production technology, and advisory services; (ii) rehabilitating a seed processing facility to increase farmer's access to improved seed; (iii) bringing land that is currently out of production back into production; (iv) training farmers on reduction of postharvest losses; (v) building of food storage capacity to support postharvest handling at the household and community levels; and (vi) provision of cash or food for work to eligible individuals. The implementation schedule will be slightly revised and the closing date of both the original project and AF will be extended to April 30, 2015." }, "project_name" : "Southern Sudan Emergency Food Crisis Response Project- AF III", "projectdocs" : [ { "DocTypeDesc" : "Project Paper (PJPR),  Vol.1 of 1", "DocType" : "PJPR", "EntityID" : "000442464_20131009102446", "DocURL" : "http://www-wds.worldbank.org/servlet/WDSServlet?pcont=details&eid=000442464_20131009102446", "DocDate" : "01-OCT-2013" }, { "DocTypeDesc" : "Project Information Document (PID),  Vol.1 of 1", "DocType" : "PID", "EntityID" : "000001843_20130618091419", "DocURL" : "http://www-wds.worldbank.org/servlet/WDSServlet?pcont=details&eid=000001843_20130618091419", "DocDate" : "07-JUN-2013" } ], "projectfinancialtype" : "OTHER", "projectstatusdisplay" : "Active", "regionname" : "Africa", "sector" : [ { "Name" : "Crops" }, { "Name" : "Other social services" }, { "Name" : "General agriculture, fishing and forestry sector" } ], "sector1" : { "Name" : "Crops", "Percent" : 50 }, "sector2" : { "Name" : "Other social services", "Percent" : 30 }, "sector3" : { "Name" : "General agriculture, fishing and forestry sector", "Percent" : 20 }, "sector_namecode" : [ { "name" : "Crops", "code" : "AH" }, { "name" : "Other social services", "code" : "JB" }, { "name" : "General agriculture, fishing and forestry sector", "code" : "AZ" } ], "sectorcode" : "AZ,JB,AH", "source" : "IBRD", "status" : "Active", "supplementprojectflg" : "Y", "theme1" : { "Name" : "Global food crisis response", "Percent" : 100 }, "theme_namecode" : [ { "name" : "Global food crisis response", "code" : "91" } ], "themecode" : "91", "totalamt" : 0, "totalcommamt" : 7530000, "url" : "http://www.worldbank.org/projects/P145339?lang=en" }
 { "_id" : { "$oid" : "52b213b38594d8a2be17c78b" }, "approvalfy" : "2014", "board_approval_month" : "October", "boardapprovaldate" : "2013-10-25T00:00:00Z", "closingdate" : "2017-12-31T00:00:00Z", "country_namecode" : "Republic of India!$!IN", "countrycode" : "IN", "countryname" : "Republic of India", "countryshortname" : "India", "docty" : "Project Appraisal Document,Environmental Assessment,Project Information Document,Integrated Safeguards Data Sheet,Working Paper", "envassesmentcategorycode" : "B", "grantamt" : 0, "ibrdcommamt" : 0, "id" : "P146653", "idacommamt" : 250000000, "lendinginstr" : "Investment Project Financing", "lendinginstrtype" : "IN", "lendprojectcost" : 250000000, "majorsector_percent" : [ { "Name" : "Transportation", "Percent" : 60 }, { "Name" : "Water, sanitation and flood protection", "Percent" : 25 }, { "Name" : "Industry and trade", "Percent" : 10 }, { "Name" : "Health and other social services", "Percent" : 5 } ], "mjsector_namecode" : [ { "name" : "Transportation", "code" : "TX" }, { "name" : "Water, sanitation and flood protection", "code" : "WX" }, { "name" : "Industry and trade", "code" : "YX" }, { "name" : "Health and other social services", "code" : "JX" } ], "mjtheme" : [ "Rural development", "Social protection and risk management", "Social protection and risk management", "Environment and natural resources management" ], "mjtheme_namecode" : [ { "name" : "Rural development", "code" : "10" }, { "name" : "Social protection and risk management", "code" : "6" }, { "name" : "Social protection and risk management", "code" : "6" }, { "name" : "Environment and natural resources management", "code" : "11" } ], "mjthemecode" : "10,6,6,11", "prodline" : "PE", "prodlinetext" : "IBRD/IDA", "productlinetype" : "L", "project_abstract" : { "cdata" : "The objective of the Uttarakhand Disaster Recovery Project for India is to restore housing, rural connectivity and build resilience of communities in Uttarakhand and increase the technical capacity of the state entities to respond promptly and effectively to an eligible crisis or emergency. There are six components to the project, the first component being resilient infrastructure reconstruction. The objective of this component is to focus on the immediate needs of reconstruction of damaged houses and public buildings. The aim is to reduce the vulnerability of the affected population and restore access to the basic services of governance. The second component is the rural road connectivity. The objective of this component is to restore the connectivity lost due to the disaster through the reconstruction of damaged roads and bridges including: village roads, Other District Roads (ODRs), bridle roads and bridle bridges. The third component is the technical assistance and capacity building for disaster risk management. The objective of this component is to enhance the capabilities of government entities and others in risk mitigation and response. The fourth component is the financing disaster response expenses. This component will support the financing of eligible expenses already incurred by the state during the immediate post-disaster response period. The fifth component is the implementation support. This component will support the incremental operating costs of the project, including the operation of the Project Management Unit (PMU) and the respective Project Implementation Units (PIUs). Finally, the sixth component is the contingency emergency response." }, "project_name" : "Uttarakhand Disaster Recovery Project", "projectdocs" : [ { "DocTypeDesc" : "Project Appraisal Document (PAD),  Vol.1 of 1", "DocType" : "PAD", "EntityID" : "000333037_20131021112627", "DocURL" : "http://www-wds.worldbank.org/servlet/WDSServlet?pcont=details&eid=000333037_20131021112627", "DocDate" : "11-OCT-2013" }, { "DocTypeDesc" : "Environmental Assessment (EA),  Vol.1 of 1", "DocType" : "EA", "EntityID" : "000442464_20131015112514", "DocURL" : "http://www-wds.worldbank.org/servlet/WDSServlet?pcont=details&eid=000442464_20131015112514", "DocDate" : "10-OCT-2013" }, { "DocTypeDesc" : "Project Information Document (PID),  Vol.1 of 1", "DocType" : "PID", "EntityID" : "000356161_20130926131319", "DocURL" : "http://www-wds.worldbank.org/servlet/WDSServlet?pcont=details&eid=000356161_20130926131319", "DocDate" : "24-SEP-2013" }, { "DocTypeDesc" : "Integrated Safeguards Data Sheet (ISDS),  Vol.1 of 1", "DocType" : "ISDS", "EntityID" : "000333037_20130926120720", "DocURL" : "http://www-wds.worldbank.org/servlet/WDSServlet?pcont=details&eid=000333037_20130926120720", "DocDate" : "24-SEP-2013" }, { "DocTypeDesc" : "Working Paper (WP),  Vol.1 of 1", "DocType" : "WP", "EntityID" : "000333037_20131115110208", "DocURL" : "http://www-wds.worldbank.org/servlet/WDSServlet?pcont=details&eid=000333037_20131115110208", "DocDate" : "01-JUN-2013" } ], "projectfinancialtype" : "IDA", "projectstatusdisplay" : "Active", "regionname" : "South Asia", "sector" : [ { "Name" : "Rural and Inter-Urban Roads and Highways" }, { "Name" : "Flood protection" }, { "Name" : "Housing construction" }, { "Name" : "Other social services" } ], "sector1" : { "Name" : "Rural and Inter-Urban Roads and Highways", "Percent" : 60 }, "sector2" : { "Name" : "Flood protection", "Percent" : 25 }, "sector3" : { "Name" : "Housing construction", "Percent" : 10 }, "sector4" : { "Name" : "Other social services", "Percent" : 5 }, "sector_namecode" : [ { "name" : "Rural and Inter-Urban Roads and Highways", "code" : "TI" }, { "name" : "Flood protection", "code" : "WD" }, { "name" : "Housing construction", "code" : "YC" }, { "name" : "Other social services", "code" : "JB" } ], "sectorcode" : "JB,YC,WD,TI", "source" : "IBRD", "status" : "Active", "supplementprojectflg" : "N", "theme1" : { "Name" : "Rural services and infrastructure", "Percent" : 60 }, "theme_namecode" : [ { "name" : "Rural services and infrastructure", "code" : "78" }, { "name" : "Natural disaster management", "code" : "52" }, { "name" : "Social risk mitigation", "code" : "87" }, { "name" : "Climate change", "code" : "81" } ], "themecode" : "81,87,52,78", "totalamt" : 250000000, "totalcommamt" : 250000000, "url" : "http://www.worldbank.org/projects/P146653?lang=en" }
```

It's worth noting that not all fields in every row have valid information, I am supposed to be identifying and rectifying that issue. I don't want the answer to that, I just want to know how to use `json_normalize` to get the info into a Pandas dataframe.

Comment: Can you add a snippet of your `data.json`

Comment: If you need any more info, let me know. I still haven't got this squared away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. reading the data line by line as strings (copied pasted your text into a file)
2. converting each string to a python dict using the json function.
3. converting each dict to a one row DF using pandas json_normalize, concatenating all the DF's if needed.

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
   import json

   with open('data.json', 'r') as f: # 'data.json' is the name of the file
       data = f.readlines()

   pd.concat([json_normalize(json.loads(j)) for j in data])
   ```