# Parse a JSON column in a df and extract specific key value

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, json-normalize

I have a pandas DataFrame containing one column with a nested JSON dict. I want to normalize the JSON column ('media') and extract the value for the key 'url' when it is present. The 'media' json payload has three types of possible media objects all included in the example data set. I need to extract from the 'MessageMediaWebPage' object, only.

The typical error (although there is some variation) after using

```
# Using JSON normalize function

pd.json_normalize(df['media'], max_level=1)
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

The full error is listed below

Data and code example in a JSON format. The example data set only consists of three records but is too large to post directly. The link is to my git:

```
# The json is nested
# The full data set consists of several columns and 40K + records. This is just a small slice.

df = pd.read_json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/whitedl/telegram/main/df_3.json', dtype = {'telegram_id':object}) 

df.info()

pd.json_normalize(df['media'], max_level=1)
```

As background I have tried the following solutions:

- [how to parse a json column in a df where we append new column using selected keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61546983/how-to-parse-a-json-column-in-a-df-where-we-append-new-column-using-selected-key)
- [pandas DataFrame: normalize one JSON column and merge with other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49671693/pandas-dataframe-normalize-one-json-column-and-merge-with-other-columns)
- [How to use json_normalize from Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45383702/how-to-use-json-normalize-from-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that value in media column is string type. You can apply `ast.literal_eval` to media column to convert it value to python dict.

```py
import ast 


pd.json_normalize(df['media'].apply(ast.literal_eval), max_level=1)
```

Comment: That does it thanks.